# Divide row values based on column criteria in a dataframe Python

Tags: python, dataframe, divide

Hi I have a dataframe which is structured as the following:

```
              School  Grade Class
Date                             
2019-01-01  School A      2  Math
2019-02-01  School A      3  Math
2019-06-01  School A      1  Math
2019-01-01  School B      4  Math
2019-02-01  School B      5  Math
2019-06-01  School B      2  Math
2019-01-01  School C      6  Math
2019-02-01  School C      5  Math
2019-06-01  School C      6  Math
```

I would like to build the ratio for the same date between the schools and add it into the same dataframe as shown below in terms of

Date: 2019-01-01    Ratio: School A Grade / School B Grade = 2/4 = 0.5 etc.

```
Date        Type               Value    Class   
2019-01-01  School A           2        Math    
2019-02-01  School A           3        Math    
2019-06-01  School A           1        Math    
2019-01-01  School B           4        Math    
2019-02-01  School B           5        Math    
2019-06-01  School B           2        Math    
2019-01-01  School C           6        Math
2019-02-01  School C           5        Math
2019-06-01  School C           6        Math
2019-01-01  School A/School B  0.5      Math    
2019-02-01  School A/School B  0.6      Math    
2019-06-01  School A/School B  0.5      Math
```

The code looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

Input = {'Date': ['2019-01-01','2019-02-01','2019-06-01', '2019-01-01','2019-02-01','2019-06-01'],
         'School': ['School A', 'School A', 'School A', 'School B', 'School B', 'School B'],
         'Grade': [2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2],
         'Class': ['Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(Input, columns = ['Date', 'School', 'Grade', 'Class'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

I am not sure how to loop (whether it is needed) over the rows and divide the dedicatied numbers based on the condition.

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to not add `Ratio` under `School`, that makes it more confusing

Comment: Yes good point I changed the field it should show the value School A/School  B

Comment: that's still weird, shouldn't you not add any new rows and just add the ratio column?

Comment: Could you add an example, maybe this would make more sense.

Comment: I changed the output making it better. I would like to have it in this style if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
df2=df[df['School']=='School A']
df2['School']='School A/School B'
df2['Grade']=df2['Grade']/df[df['School']=='School B']['Grade']
result=pd.concat([df, df2])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
                       School  Grade Class
Date
2019-01-01           School A    2.0  Math
2019-02-01           School A    3.0  Math
2019-06-01           School A    1.0  Math
2019-01-01           School B    4.0  Math
2019-02-01           School B    5.0  Math
2019-06-01           School B    2.0  Math
2019-01-01  School A/School B    0.5  Math
2019-02-01  School A/School B    0.6  Math
2019-06-01  School A/School B    0.5  Math
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just take care of possible discrepancies on Date-School pairs (eg if there is no School B value for some date, etc). In that case you should add some empty row manually, or ignore the assosiated value of School A for that Date. Let me know if you need any help with that. 
If there are no discrepancies, there will be no issue. Cheers

Comment: this assumes a sorted dataframe, this would not work if values were not sorted, ideally this should use `groupby` to get around that

Comment: @gold_cy yes this works for this specific data frame input. However it is easy to adjust any similar dataframe to this format, with some sorting and some filling in case there are school gaps for some dates, as i explained above

Comment: no point to sort when you can juts use `groupby`....

Comment: @gold_cy, could you please provide your example?

Comment: I just posted a solution using `groupby` which does not care if data is sorted, however be aware this won't work as expected if there is more than two values on a given day

Comment: @gold_cy thanks a lot. Somehow I am using pycharm and these two modules are not supported there :(. Is there another solution?

Comment: both of those modules are in the standard library so not sure what is up with your settings....

Comment: @gold_cy yes wou are right. Could you post the full code because i receive nan for school and class using the example below

Comment: please comment on my answer as opposed to this one if there is further clarification needed, I updated it

Answer (score 0):

Try using `groupby` to avoid the issue where dates are not sorted.

```
from operator import truediv
from functools import reduce

schools = ["School A", "School B"]
df1 = df.loc[df.School.isin(schools)]
grades = pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby(df1.index)["Grade"].agg(lambda s: reduce(truediv, s)))
grades["School"] = "School A / School B"
grades["Class"] = "Math"

pd.concat([df1, grades])

                         School  Grade Class
Date                                        
2019-01-01             School A    2.0  Math
2019-02-01             School A    3.0  Math
2019-06-01             School A    1.0  Math
2019-01-01             School B    4.0  Math
2019-02-01             School B    5.0  Math
2019-06-01             School B    2.0  Math
2019-01-01  School A / School B    0.5  Math
2019-02-01  School A / School B    0.6  Math
2019-06-01  School A / School B    0.5  Math
```

Comment: I understood, but this solution would not work if I would have additional schools in place e.g. School C. I just need that for dedicated schools and there are a lot and I just had a minimal example. Is there also a solution for that in place?

Comment: the other solution would not work either if there are more than 2 schools. please provide the logic for finding the ratio when it is more than 2 schools and we can go from there.

Comment: extended the examples above

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped. But you mentioned if there are not equal dates with values. How could i ignore these and just calculate the values where the dates are equal.

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses a deepcopy of the dataframes and select the data. And then both df can be divided.

```
import pandas as pd

Input = {'Date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-06-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-06-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-06-01'],
         'School': ['School A', 'School A', 'School A', 'School A', 'School A', 'School B', 'School B', 'School B', 'School C', 'School C', 'School C'],
         'Grade': [1, 6, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 6, 5, 6],
         'Class': ['Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Math']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(Input, columns = ['Date', 'School', 'Grade', 'Class'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.set_index('Date')

df_copy_A = df.copy(deep=True)
df_copy_B = df.copy(deep=True)

df_copy_A = df_copy_A[(df_copy_A['School'] == 'School A')]
df_copy_B = df_copy_B[(df_copy_B['School'] == 'School B')]
df_copy_B['School'] = 'School A / School B'

df_copy_B['Grade'] = df_copy_B['Grade'].rdiv(df_copy_A['Grade'])


df = pd.concat([df, df_copy_B])
print(df)
```

Which resulted in the expected output:

```
                         School  Grade Class
Date                                        
2018-01-01             School A    1.0  Math
2018-02-01             School A    6.0  Math
2019-01-01             School A    2.0  Math
2019-02-01             School A    3.0  Math
2019-06-01             School A    1.0  Math
2019-01-01             School B    4.0  Math
2019-02-01             School B    5.0  Math
2019-06-01             School B    2.0  Math
2019-01-01             School C    6.0  Math
2019-02-01             School C    5.0  Math
2019-06-01             School C    6.0  Math
2019-01-01  School A / School B    0.5  Math
2019-02-01  School A / School B    0.6  Math
2019-06-01  School A / School B    0.5  Math
```